# Выбор следующего элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код:

```
<div id="block">
<span></span>
</div>

$('#block').click(function(){
  $(this, 'span').addClass('content');
});
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Не работает. Нужно для span добавить класс.

Comment: @aa22, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ясно, сразу не понял, о чем речь и что не работает.

Вы неправильно используете выборку, по документации `$(выражение, контекст)`, то есть поменять местами надо this и 'span'.

```
$('#block').click(function(){
  $('span', this).addClass('content');
});
```

Comment: этот код добавляет класс content к div-у. А к span-y как вариант сделать так http://jsfiddle.net/ftf6Ltww/2/

Comment: Да, код работает. Но добавляет он класс для div, а нужно для span

Comment: mountpoint спасибо, работает

Comment: Еще возник вопрос: а как через .toggle() сделать, чтоб один раз кликнул -  один класс прибавился, второй - второй? Он почему-то добавляет display none.

Comment: @aa22, согласно [документации](http://jquery-docs.ru/) функция [toggle()](http://jquery-docs.ru/Effects/toggle/) не предназначена для таких действий. Она показывает или скрывает элемент в зависимости от текущего состояния. Если надо добавлять классы, можно использовать проверку hasClass с последующим addClass. Если при клике добавлять или убирать один класс, то toggleClass(). В общем, смотрите документацию(оф. или русский перевод), там и примеры есть в дополнение.

Comment: спасибо) разобрались уже)

Answer (score 0):

А разве не так? Судя по вопросу, внутри только спан?

```
$('#block').click(function(){
  $(this).children().addClass('content');
});
```

И с переключалкой один раз-два раза:

```
$('#block').click(function(){
    if( $(this).children().hasClass('first')) {
    $(this).children().addClass('second');
    } else {
    $(this).children().addClass('first');
    }
});
```